# How to listen click button in every activity

Tags: android, android-activity, click, listener

I want to get text of clicked button in every activity in any time.
For example how can I get text of end call button from call activity.

Is any way to access UI element of an activity (like call activity)?

This is my code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + telNumber));
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in started activity how can I access to UI element like EndButton.

Comment: you can use [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) for that

Comment: you seem dont understand my question. i know how to use PhoneStateListener but i want just access to end call button!

Answer (score 0):

A general method to reference a UI element is to get it through it's ID.

**Example:** Say you require to get text of a text field of your activity.
To get the text of a text-field,ie, TextView ,you need to assign a variable by finding the UI element through it's ID and then apply functions such as setText() or getText().

```
TextView myText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.one_you_gave_in_UI);
String text=myText.getText();
```

or either you can Toast it like:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

Although if you need the text written on the button of UI,then

```
Button myButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ID_in_UI);
String message= myButton.getText();
```

The string message your text required.

Comment: i know , but this work just for activity that you have the id, but for activity like Call activity (Intent.Action_Call) how can i access to id and Ui elements.

Comment: call findViewByID with the activity name ,like, 

TextView myText=(TextView) ActivityCall.findViewById(R.id.one_you_gave_in_UI);

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I unable to get your first question, but as you ask: way to access UI element of an activity. yes It is so simple..

**you have to get View of activity:**

```
Button mButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yourid);
```

You have to call call getActivity() to get the Instance of Activity